# Entry with Icon at the right side

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is there a way to achieve this entry plus an icon at xamarin forms, without going through platform specific effects/renders, cause right now in order to achieve this, I have implemented a platform effect for this. Please check the image link below:

[EntryImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xBBN.jpg)

EDIT1: Changed link

Comment: There is a way of doing this inside the entry itself by manipulating the OS control through custom renderers, take a look here for full example https://www.qimata.com/?p=7071

Comment: Sorry @Depechie, right now I am trying to avoid custom renderers. Like I said, I've done this by using android platform effects. But I am trying to look into avoiding it as much as possible (unless it is really needed - like no way of doing it cross platform wise) since the app I am trying to create supports all 3 platforms, Android, iOS, UWP. Plus, I am not just doing it for the sake of the icon at the side, there is a purpose for that icon.

Comment: Understandable :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best solution is to create a Grid with 1 rows and 2 columns.
In column 0 you add your Entry and in column 1 you add your icon. If you want you can set your Entry to occupy column 1 and 2

Comment: I have tried this, yes, it's beside the entry, but I want the icon to be overlapping to the entry itself in order for the image to make use of the entry's border also.

Comment: Okay, I tried occupying the two columns for the entry, it overlapped. I will now try to set the location of the icon to be at the end of the entry

Comment: Thanks. This gave me an idea on how to do things. I already done this, I'll post the answer tomorrow. But I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 8):

For anyone who is wondering how I used @Alessandro 's answer, here's how it is.

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
    <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Entry Placeholder="Test" 
                   Text="Test"
                   Grid.Row="0"
                   Grid.Column="0"
                   Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                   />

            <Image Source="test_image.png"
                   Grid.Row="0"
                   Grid.Column="1"
                   Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
                   HorizontalOptions="End">

</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Entry with Icon at the right side**

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="0">
 <Entry IsPassword="True" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
 <Image Source="icon.png" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50"/>
</StackLayout>
```